# Differentiating both sides of a DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential-algebra

In general if you have a differential equation with two variables such that:
$$L(x,y)=h_1[f(x),f'(x),f^{(2)}(x),...,f^{(n)}(x),g(y),g'(y),g^{(2)}(y),...,g^{(n)}(y)]\\
R(x,y)=h_2[f(x),f'(x),f^{(2)}(x),...,f^{(n)}(x),g(y),g'(y),g^{(2)}(y),...,g^{(n)}(y)]\\
L(x,y)=R(x,y)
$$
Does the following hold true?
$$\frac{\partial^a}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial^b}{\partial y^b}L(x,y)=\frac{\partial^a}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial^b}{\partial y^b}R(x,y),\phantom{..........} \forall a\in\mathbb{Z},\forall b\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Ah yes my error! Corrected

Comment: $L-R=0$ so I think it holds, when the derivatives exist.

Comment: Well, $L(x,y)$ and $R(x,y)$ are different functions, so this is more of a general question inquiring if the derivative of both sides of a general PDE still render the solutions tp the resulting PDE correct

Comment: $\dot x=0$ and $\ddot x=0$ differ.

Comment: This may be incorrect because we need to consider the initial and/or boundary condition.

Comment: Well essentially I was attempting a separation of variables and so I attempted to do the following I had the following equation:
$A+BP(x)L(y)=\frac{L(y)}{L'(y)}*f(x)$, and so to separate it I took the derivative with respect to 'L' of both sides assuming $\frac{\partial}{\partial L}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial L}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{L'(y)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and so then the equation was separable, but I am wondering if this is a legitimate operation

Comment: I don't think this is legitimate. It gives a different PDE/ODE. A broader range solution may get. But I don't know in what sense it is broader.

Comment: Okay, I'll buy it, then if not legitimate, why? Or, are the solutions of the old DE be obtainable from the solutions of the new one, and how?

Comment: You mean the solution of the old DE will satisfy the new DE?

Comment: For instance, the solution to the coupled DE: $\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dy}=f(x)g(y)$ yields the solution $f(x)=c_1e^{Sx}$ & $g(y)=c_2e^{\frac{y}{S}}$ where as the solution of the DE after taking the derivative with respect to x, and then y of both sides yields $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\frac{d^2g}{dy^2}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dy}$. The solution to this equation is $f(x)=c_2e^{Sx}-\frac{c_1}{S}$ & $g(y)=c_4e^{\frac{y}{S}}-c3$. This solution can be made identical to the first if $c_1$ and $c_3$ are made to be zero. So then this would imply that there exist constants such that the equality is true, no?

Comment: That is reasonable. But it can't go back. You don't know how to `set zeros`. Maybe you will know if you dig deeper.

Comment: Pardon me? "Set Zeros"?

Comment: "if c1 and c3 are made to be zero"

Comment: Haha I see. Interesting. Well thanks for your input, in any case!